# Adding conditional probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Consider the following chart

[image]

Now if we have to find $P(S \vert A)$ where $S$ is "has cough" and $A$ is "has cold" what would be its value. Is this the correct expression:

$$
P(S\vert A) = \frac{0.7525 \times0.505}{0.7525 + 0.505}=0.304?
$$

Full question is [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsd5j.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Tim Is the answer 0.304 correct?

Comment: Put the whole problem in the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This table does not provide enough information to answer the desired question.** The table provides information *only* about the probability of a cough given the other factors, but it says nothing about the probability of each factor.

The joint distribution of three binary random variables can be described fully by $2^3 = 8$ probabilities. These probabilities must sum to $1$ however, so there just $7$ "pieces of information" needed. This table provides only $4$ pieces of information, because the second column is always minus the first column.

For instance, the target probability can be expressed as

\begin{align*}
P(\text{Cough} | \text{Cold}) &= P(\text{Cough} | \text{Cold}, LD) P(LD) + P(\text{Cough} | \text{Cold}, LD^c) P(LD^c) \\
&= 0.7525\times P(LD) + 0.505\times (1 - P(LD))
\end{align*}

But with this table, there is no discernable way to calculate $P(LD)$, the probability of lung disease.

---

**Edit with new information in the comment.**

In a comment, the OP links to more tables providing additional information.

[image]

The marginal probability of lung disease can be calculated from the two tables in the top left.

\begin{align*}
P(LD) &= P(LD|S)P(S) + P(LD|S^c)P(S^c) \\
&= (0.1009)(0.2) + (0.001)(0.8) \\
&= 0.02098
\end{align*}

We can plug this in to the earlier expression to get a final answer.

$$P(\text{Cough}|\text{Cold}) = (0.7525)(0.02098) + (0.505)(1 - 0.02098) = 0.5101925$$

Comment: [Question](https://i.imgur.com/tAIvXYp.png) this is the full image

Comment: @ancadancad see the edit

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

To me, this table looks like the conditional probability distribution $P(S \vert A, L)$  where $S$ is the variable corresponding to "cough", $A$ is the variable corresponding to "cold" and $L$ is the variable corresponding to "lung disease".  Each of these variables can take on the values $True, False$.

In my notation, you are asking about the specific probability $P(S=T \vert A=T)$, where I've made the True/False distinction explicit.  As far as I know, this can only be obtained by marginalizing out the lung variable

$$
P(S=T \vert A=T) = \sum_{L \in \lbrace T, F \rbrace} P(S=T \vert A=T, L) P(L)
$$

You have not specified the prior distribution over $L$, i.e. $P(L)$, so the conditional probability you want cannot be computed from just the information in this table.

Comment: Thanks for this information